# Why repolarization in ventricles start in last area which is depolarized "epicardium " rather than first area "endocardium"

Tags: physiology, cardiology, action-potential

About ventricular repolarization , l know it start in the last area which is depolarized ( that is why it has positive deflection on ECG ) but the question is why it start in that area ( epicardium ) although l think it can begain in first area depolarized "septum and endocardium" ?
- I heard answer about blood supply is differ because period of contraction is more in the "endocardium" than in"epicardium" which will generate high pressure inside ventricles that decrease coronary blood flow then slow repolarization phase ! If this true So how blood flow can effect repolarization ?

Comment: It isn't at all clear to me what you are asking. Also, "cardiophysiology" is not helpful as a title, your title needs to include your question or at least something close to a question.

Comment: I added some information and l hope you understand what l'm asking for .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is pericardium muscle repolarizated earlier than endocardium?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/28509/why-is-pericardium-muscle-repolarizated-earlier-than-endocardium)